# TortoiseHg shelve-update-unshelve shortcut

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, shelving

Using *TortoiseHg Workbench*, almost every time I pull from a remote repository, I have uncommitted code changes so that I need to shelve them before I update and then unshelve them again.

Is there a way to do this all in one click? I seem to remember being able to do this when I used Git (perhaps with *GitHub for Windows*).

Comment: Add own tool (button) to Custom Toolbar?

Comment: @Lazy Badger Do you have a link for any documentation or examples on how to customise the toolbar with my own buttons. I can't find anything except some broken links.

Comment: For me adding button seems as *obvious thing* in THG's GUI, sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic shelve before pulling in Mercurial (with TortoiseHG)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207762/automatic-shelve-before-pulling-in-mercurial-with-tortoisehg)

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up or comments

Tried to add button to THG GUI

1. Defined new tool in Tools menu

[image]

2. Added to toolbar (failed, no buttom on toolbar, I suppose, due to icon size /small/ - using path to big icon file instead of embedded may change visibility result)

[image]

3. Tried to add to Revision Context Menu and use added feature

[image]

As you can see - button added, but command failed (for unknown reason): using plain `hg` for `PATH\hg.exe` is recommendation from "Define tool" window from THG